# Can i use component created with angular 7 in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7

I'm creating a web app using Angular 7 and ionic 4 but I really have a lot of common components. I've created libraries and build them using ng build library-name. In the other side I have installed shared libraries using `npm install../myproject/dist/sharedlibrary ..` but ionic 4 keeps showing:

> error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: